# 'docker: invalid reference format' when docker repository is not explicitly specified

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm running a Docker in Docker container in kubernetes through the Gitlab CI (there is a main image and dind is as a service). In the pod I can build docker images and push them, however any further manipulation or a simple docker run triggers an error of invalid reference format.

There are two additional insecure private repositories specified in the dind service specification. If I try to run docker images without a repo prefix specified, it fails. (note that the images are there, it's just their tag which doesn't have the repo specified)

```
bash-4.2# docker run hello-world
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
bash-4.2# docker run docker.io/hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

bash-4.2#
```

I would expect the basic docker pull/run commands to pass and to use the images cached in the daemon even when their current tag doesn't contain a repository specified.

Added docker info

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 21
Server Version: 18.09.5
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: bb71b10fd8f58240ca47fbb579b9d1028eea7c84
runc version: 2b18fe1d885ee5083ef9f0838fee39b62d653e30
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.35-1844.3.2.el7uek.x86_64
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.9 (containerized)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 20
Total Memory: 125.5GiB
Name: runner-vppr4q7s-project-14503-concurrent-08qxbj
ID: HQ3U:HATA:TZUT:OLVS:MHRZ:F4DY:ENBD:Z5WH:FQBC:SGI3:BUUY:QIME
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
HTTP Proxy: xxxxxxxx
HTTPS Proxy: xxxxxxx
No Proxy: localhost,127.0.0.1,.xxxxxxxxxx
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 xxxxxxxxxxxx:5000
 yyyyyyyyyyyy:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine

WARNING: API is accessible on http://0.0.0.0:2375 without encryption.
         Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
         to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
         more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
Registries:
```

Additionally:

```
bash-4.2# docker tag docker.io/hello-world:latest hello-world:v1
Error parsing reference: "hello-world:v1" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
bash-4.2# docker tag docker.io/hello-world:latest some:2000/hello-world:v1
bash-4.2# docker tag docker.io/hello-world:latest docker.io/hello-world:v1
(ok)
```

And `docker images` doesn't show  the `docker.io/hello-world:latest` and `docker.io/hello-world:v1` but shows `some:2000/hello-world:v1`

Comment: Did you copy/paste the first command? Check for unknown characters like windows linefeeds in linux scripts, or the wrong dash/hyphen character.

Comment: no, it's written manually and the second is the same just with the repo prepended

Comment: Sounds like a modified docker engine, please include the output of `docker info`

Comment: I'm not seeing the cause from those logs, best guess is a modified engine, but the build numbers are identical to docker:18.09.5-dind that I just tested with locally. I'm not able to reproduce here, so this may be specific to gitlab.

Comment: One other thought is to check for an alias or wrapper around the docker CLI. Check `type docker`

Comment: Apologies for not making a comment. I'll respond here:

1) The "type docker" command returns the same binary for both users
2) The "docker info" command returns the same result for both users